# how to combine two next if together

Tags: perl

I have a script that run on the list of files to do some of the changes, each file of them has a call event and the call event details contains 4 elements so i just want to do the changes on 2 of them only here I'm stuck with how to combine two `next if` in one loop, here I have used 2 loops to do the job but it takes more time , is there any idea about how to do that ?

```
my $calleventtag = $struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'};
my @indexes = reverse (grep { exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'supplServiceEvent'} } 0..$#$calleventtag);

    my $sup_event_cnt = $#indexes;

    foreach my $index (@indexes)
    {
    splice (@$calleventtag , $index,1);
    }
foreach (0..$#$calleventtag)
    {
    next if ( ! exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}) ;

        if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'destinationNetwork'} )
        {
            delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'destinationNetwork'};
        }

        if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} 
        && $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} !~ m/^96279/ 
        )
        {
            delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'mobileOriginatedCall'}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'};
        }

    }
foreach (0..$#$calleventtag)
    {
next if ( ! exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'});

    if ( exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'}->{'gprsBasicCallInformation'}->{'gprsDestination'}->{'accessPointNameOI'} )
            {
                delete $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'}->{'gprsBasicCallInformation'}->{'gprsDestination'}->{'accessPointNameOI'};
            }
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm stuck with how to combine two next if in one loop, here I have used 2 loops to do the job ..."* The second loop does not have a `next if`. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry there was a missing like before gprscall if statement , `next if ( ! exists $calleventtag->[$_]->{'gprsCall'});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (...) {
   next if ...;

   ...
}
```

can also be written as

```
for (...) {
   if (!...) {
      ...
   }
}
```

You could use the following:

```
use Data::Diver qw( Dive );

my $call_event_details = Dive($struct, qw( transferBatch callEventDetails ));

for my $call_event_detail (@$call_event_details) {
   next if !$call_event_detail->{supplServiceEvent};

   if ( my $bci = Dive($call_event_detail, qw( mobileOriginatedCall basicCallInformation )) ) {
      delete $bci->{destinationNetwork};

      if ( my $scs = $bci->{simChargeableSubscriber} ) {
         my $msisdc = $scs->{msisdn};
         delete $scs->{msisdn} if $msisdc && $msisdc !~ /^96279/;
      }
   }

   if ( my $dest = Dive($call_event_detail, qw( gprsCall gprsBasicCallInformation gprsDestination )) ) {
      delete $dest->{accessPointNameOI};
   }
}
```

Notes:

- The quotes around string literals aren't needed in hash indexes if the string is valid valid identifier. For example, `$hash->{'foo'}` can be written as `$hash->{foo}`.
- `->` isn't needed between two indexes. For example, `$hash->{foo}->{bar}` can be written as `$hash->{foo}{bar}`.
- If a hash element is either a reference or doesn't exist, you don't need to use `exists` to check if you have a reference; you can use a simple truth test since references are always true.
- [BUG FIX] `$hash->{foo}{bar}` can autovivify `$hash->{foo}` (cause a reference to be assigned to it), so your tests to check if stuff exists could actually be causing things to be created. To fix this, you can replace

  ```
  if ($hash->{foo}{bar})
  ```

  with

  ```
  if ($hash->{foo} && $hash->{foo}{bar})
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (Dive($hash, qw( foo bar )))
  ```
- Using the same long chain of indexes (`->{foo}{bar}{baz}`) repeatedly is error prone.
- It's best to use plural names for arrays. First, it's more descriptive, but it also makes choosing names for loop variables easier.
- Speaking of variable names, why would use `$calleventtag` for the name of the variable containing `callEventDetails` nodes?
- You don't need to check if a hash element exists before trying to delete it; `delete` can be passed an element that doesn't exist.
- No need to loop over the indexes of an array if you don't need the indexes.
- `grep` was a good choice, but `splice` was not. You should have used: `$calleventtag = [ grep { ... } @$calleventtag ];`. I moved the check into the loop.

Comment: brother its worked fine with me but currently im using the script on `sun solaris 10`and its return the below messages : `Use of uninitialized value in length at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/Convert/ASN1/_decode.pm line 58.` and `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string..`

Comment: Neither `length`, concatenation/interpolation nor Convert::ASN1 is used in the code in my answer.